# Problems with sealed class hierarchies in Kotlin

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

I am following the MVI pattern in Android. I have the following code:

```
sealed class AttendLeaveEventResult : UseCaseResult<AttendLeaveEventResult>(){
}
sealed class UseCaseResult<R> {
    open class SomeFetching<R> : UseCaseResult<R>()
    data class Success<R>(val result: R) : UseCaseResult<R>()
    data class Failure<R>(val error: Throwable) : UseCaseResult<R>()
}
```

However, when I move the UseCaseResult class into its own file, I get an error:

```
Cannot access <init>: it is private in UseCaseResult
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sealed classes inside another class in Kotlin can't be compiled: cannot access '<init>' it is private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054789/sealed-classes-inside-another-class-in-kotlin-cant-be-compiled-cannot-access)

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? If you want to make your class `AttendLeaveEventResult` a child of a sealed class `UseCaseResult`, it must be in the same file. If you want to wrap `AttendLeaveEventResult ` into `UseCaseResult`, you have to instantiate it directly, for example: `Success(AttendLeaveEventResult())`. `AttendLeaveEventResult` should not extend anything.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, an error will be thrown if subclasses of sealed class are not in the same file or not as nested subclasses.

refer this for further details: [Sealed classes inside another class in Kotlin can't be compiled: cannot access '<init>' it is private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054789/sealed-classes-inside-another-class-in-kotlin-cant-be-compiled-cannot-access)